# How can i make AssetBundle in Unity runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I need to load asset in runtime.
my targat is fbx format, but it's not major... i buy Trilib, it support fbx partly.

I know assetBundle is the only way for me. but as far as i know, it can build only Unity editor mode.

i need this.
download new fbx file from server, convert(build) to assetBundle, load it.

i don't want open another unity project and select import asset, click build assetbundle button, send assetbundle to server and download it.
all process must by one button click (every process in code).

i see a quetions, he say create Assetbundle (build assetBundle) is only available on the Editor for Editor plugins only. is it real? and not exist paid asset for this??

can i do it?

please help me!

Comment: This seems similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406392/how-to-convert-3ds-fbx-model-into-asset-bundle-at-run-time-after-downloading-f?noredirect=1&lq=1) But I dont believe AssetBundle is what will work for you. You would have to load the model somewhere and import it at runtime using some library, either from the store or made by yourself. Something like Assimp. And fbx might not be the easiest format for doing this.

Comment: instead of using asset bundles consider converting ur model to gltf using node.js / C++ on the server side, then importing with https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF

Answer (score 0):

Its possible with asset bundles (Free Version),You can download assets from server and you can build apk/ios app as well and it works fine.

Comment: um, i think you misunderstand my question. my questions is how can i build assetbundle without editor mode.(runtime) 
i already know how to use assetbundle.(already build in editor).
thanks for answer.